# Get value(s) of column(s) from the selected row?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a Excel spead-sheet that looks something like this:

ZIP----------Latitude----------Longitude

The ZIP column are empty. I would like to be able to get the value of the Latitude and Longitude column when I click on the row. The Lat/Long already has values filled in.

The reason why I need this is because once those values are obtained, I'll be using it to grab data from Google Map's API http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=29.6412902,-95.0297534&sensor=false and fill in the ZIP column with the Zip Code from the Google Map data.

How would I go about obtaining the values of column B and C, which are Latitude and Longitude, when that row is selected?

Comment: `Lat/Long already has values` then later you ask `...go about obtaining the values of...Latitude and Longitude` What??????

Answer (score 0):

Might as well build some sort of static data structure in your module scope so that other subs can pull lat/lon from a clearly defined source.

```
Type GeoCoord
Dim Lat as Double
Dim Lon As Double
Dim Zip as Long
End Type

'count how many rows you have...
Dim rowcount as Long
rowcount = 'get creative here

Dim Coords() As GeoCoord
ReDim Coords(1 to rowcount)

For i=1 to rowcount
    With Coords(i)
        .Lat = cells()....' I'm sure you can figure this part out
        .Lon = cells()....' same here
    End With
Next
```

'then do your URL stuff here if you want...

something like...

```
Coords(i).Zip = 'value from google maps API
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rw as Range, Lat, Lngt

For Each rw in selection.rows
    Lat = rw.entirerow.cells(2).value
    Lngt = rw.entirerow.cells(3).value
    rw.entirerow.cells(4).value = GetZip(Lat, Lngt)
Next rw
```